# Can SQL 2008 Geospatial data give me Country,State,city info?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, geography

I don't know SQL Geospatial new feature.

I'm wondering if I can use to make something like:

- Map a point in a world map
- Know the country the point is located
- The points location state, and the city.
- Measure how much deliveries I have per state.
- Can all of this be done to a geometry form like a rectangle?

I mean can I make and app that allows you to insert delivery locations on a map and then make some BI analysis on this info?

Are the types Geometry and Geography suited for this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the point in SQL Server, and the geographic extensions can do things like handle polygons and testing the points for being in the polygons.

Without a database of state,city,etc polygon definitions, you will need a Geocoding service. Eg. One of the Bing Maps web services, or a desktop solution such as MapPoint.

Comment: so I need to find a way to build a "world" using polygons? And If I use a custom code I'll have to have my points coordinates on this "world". Or If I use Geocoding service, how do I correlate the points to the service? This is a bit cloudy for me.

Comment: The 'points' are standard coordinates that any Geocoding service will be able to use. And no - you should not 'build a world using polygons'... you should use an existing Geocoding service. You could then store the resulting political divisions you get in your database if you like, to make quick queries for "all entries in Country X" easier.

Comment: Slight correction on my part, you need Reverse Geocoding rather than (forward) Geocoding. Reverse Geocoding takes a coordinate and tells you the street address or place. it sounds like you don't need all that detail, so just take country, state, city.